# Laravel query not working when using as scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to find records by time interval. In table there are columns like 'date_from' and 'date_to', those are specify starts and ends date of an event.

```
public function scopeByTimeInterval($query, $dateInterval)
{
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($dateInterval) {
        [$from, $to] = $dateInterval;
        $query->where([
            ['date_from', '<=', $from],
            ['date_to', '>=', $to]
        ]);
        $query->orWhere([
            ['date_from', '>=', $from],
            ['date_to', '<=', $to]
        ]);
        $query->orWhereBetween('date_from', $dateInterval);
        $query->orWhereBetween('date_to', $dateInterval);
    });
}
```

when I use `where` query directly, there are no problem. I can see all events between those dates. But if I use it as a scope, it returns me every events in given year and month and not the interval..

What might cause kind of behavior ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Your query is basically selecting everything! Can you share what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Rwd I'm appriciate for your reply, but unfo, your queries returns very mistaken results.

Comment: In that case please can you say/share what you're trying to achieve, or explain how/why the answers aren't giving you the results you want. This way you're more likely to get the help you're looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, your query is essentially selecting everything. If you're trying to get the events that are happening during the `$from` and `$to` dates you could do something like:

```
public function scopeDateInterval($query, $interval)
{
    [$from, $to] = $interval;

    $query
        ->where(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query
                ->where(function ($query) use ($from) {
                    $query
                        ->where('date_from', '<=', $from)
                        ->where('date_to', '>=', $from);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($to) {
                    $query
                        ->where('date_from', '<=', $to)
                        ->where('date_to', '>=', $to);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                    $query
                        ->where('date_from', '>=', $from)
                        ->where('date_to', '<=', $to);
                });

        });
}
```

The above is basically saying where the `$from` or `$to` is between the start and end dates, or the start and end dates are between the `$from` and `$to`.

Answer (score -1):

Think you miss `return $query->where...`

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain?

Comment: You don't need to return from scopes.